# Cannot find SNIServerName class

Tags: java, ssl, sni

I am working with SSL connections using `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`. I upgraded from `java 1.7` to `java 1.8`. I need to set SNI host names in SSLParameters using `javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setServerNames(List<SNIServerName> serverNames)`. But the compiler cannot resolve the class SNIServerName. The compiler displays this error:

> unable to resolve class javax.net.ssl.SNIServerName

My java version:

> java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

How do I import SNIServerName or SNIHostName? AFAIK they have been introduced in Java 8. Is there an issue with my java version?

Comment: If you are using an IDE , check the target version of java for your project, this seems to be a mistake in the IDE configuration

Comment: I am using IDE for editing purpose only. I compile using mvn on command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that your JAVA_HOME is correctly configured. Just follow the steps mentioned below

```
vim ~/.bashrc
JAVA_HOME = <path to your java8 bin>
PATH = $JAVA_HOME:$PATH
save this and then
source ~/.bashrc
```

after this just verify by $JAVA_HOME on your terminal.